# Incrementally adding 1 to two different values per key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

EDIT: Added example code at the bottom

I'm using dictionaries to keep track of two values for a given key.  As an example, I want to keep track of how many balls and strikes a couple baseball players get.  So I have two baseball players:

1. Tim
2. Mark

All of there stats are listed in a text file like:

- Tim gets a strike
- Tim gets a ball
- Tim gets a strike
- Mark gets a ball

And so on and so forth.  So for the first line, the dictionary would like this (reflecting Tim getting a strike).

```
stats = {'tim', [1, 0]}
```

Then he gets a ball:

```
stats = {'tim', [1, 1]}
```

Then another strike:

```
stats = {'tim', [2, 1]}
```

Then Mark gets a ball:

```
stat = {'tim', [2, 1],
       'mark', [0, 1]}
```

Started tackling this by creating two dictionaries (one for strikes, one for balls), but I ran into two problems:

1. When I attempted to append value from strikes to balls for one player I ran into the error:

   `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I'm assuming this means append() doesn't work for integers, but I'm not sure.  I also tried using str() to change the value, but ran into the same error.

2. Even if I could solve this problem, I need to put in 0's when a strike or ball is not recorded.

Here's the general code I have at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

strike = {}
ball = {}

with open("baseball_stats.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        player = re.search(r"^\s*([a-zA-Z]+)", line)
        name = player.group(1)
        if "strike" in line:
            if name in strike:
                strike[name] += 1
            else:
                strike[name] = 1
        else:
            if name in ball:
                ball[name] += 1
            else:
                ball[name] = 1

## This is where I tried to combine the tow into the Strike dictionary and add 0's when no strikes where recorded

for key, value in ball.items():
   if key in strike.keys():
       addBall = ball[key]
       strike[key].append(addBall)
   else:
       strike[key] = 0
       addBall = ball[key]
       strike[key].append(addBall)
```

Basically, I think I'm going about this all wrong and figured I ask for guidance.  Let me know if I need to elaborate on anything.  Anything helps!

Comment: Show us your code.  If the name isn't present, you need to set it to [0.0] to start.  You never want to append values.  You will always have two integers.

Comment: Dictionaries seem to be a bad way to approach this. I would suggest pandas. Can try to put something together if that will do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough . Your description of the error message is not sufficient to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem. It is important to *read* and *understand* error messages for your own effort ([since you are supposed to try first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)), and we can only take our shot at it if you give us that info.

Comment: You should also start by trying to describe the intended logic of your code, step by step, in plain English. You may find it helps to take a real pencil and piece of paper, and draw a flowchart. But consider: what if you tried to build the dictionary directly? Say you encounter `Tim gets a strike`. Suppose `Tim` is not already in the dictionary; what should be put into the dictionary in order to reflect the strike? (hint: how many strikes does he have now? How many balls does he have now?) If he is already in the dictionary, what would the value look like? How should you change it?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on keeping more stats per player later, a nested dictionary is probably best. The defaultdict class (from collections) will make this easy to use.

Input:

```
events = ["Jim ball",
          "Jim strike",
          "Jim strike",
          "Jim ball",
          "Jim strike out",
          "Tom ball",
          "Tom hit out",
          "Mark strike",
          "Mark ball",
          "Mark hit onBase" ]
```

Process:

```
from collections import defaultdict
players = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
for event in events:
    player,*keywords = event.split()
    for stat in keywords:
        players[player][stat] += 1
```

Output:

```
print(players)

defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fc0f9996400>, 
{'Jim': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, 
        {'ball': 2, 'strike': 3, 'out': 1}), 
 'Tom': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, 
        {'ball': 1, 'hit': 1, 'out': 1}), 
'Mark': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, 
        {'strike': 1, 'ball': 1, 'hit': 1, 'onBase': 1})
})

print(players['Jim']['ball']) # 2
print(sum(stats['strike'] for stats in players.values())) # 4 
print(max(players,key=lambda p:players[p]['ball'])) # Jim
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solution to your problem (and yes, you should post your code so people can try to help!):

```
events = [["Tim", "strike"],
["Tim", "ball"],
["Tim" , "strike"],
["Mark", "ball"]]

res = {}
for e in events:
    player = res.get(e[0], [0, 0])
    if e[1] == "strike":
        player[0] += 1
    elif e[1] == "ball":
        player[1] += 1
    res[e[0]] = player

 print(res)
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks nikeros!